# iPad app - Submission to app store

Tags: ipad, orientation

Is it necessary to make my app work in both orientations "Landscape" and "Portrait" so that apple won't reject the app?
I'm planning to create my app that works only in landscope mode.
Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works in Landscape, it should also work in landscape upside-down.  Same with the portrait and portrait upside-down pair.  I have seen iPad apps that only work in 2 of the 4 orientations, as per the above, accepted into the App store, because that makes sense for the app (example: a piano app which only displays the keyboard the long way across the display, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have several apps that only work in one or other orientation, whilst not encouraged, it's not an automatic fail